# How to convert some character into five digit unicode one in Python 3.3?

Tags: python, regex, unicode, python-3.3

I'd like to convert some character into five digit unicode on in Python 3.3.
For example,

```
import re
print(re.sub('a', u'\u1D15D', 'abc' ))
```

but the result is different from what I expected.
Do I have to put the character itself, not codepoint?
Is there a better way to handle five digit unicode characters?

Comment: The `u''` literal in Python 3 is a no-op; just use `''` instead, that's already unicode.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Python unicode escapes either are [4 hex digits (`\uabcd`) or 8 (`\Uabcdabcd`)](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#index-18); for a codepoint beyond U+FFFF you need to use the latter (a capital U), make sure to left-fill with enough zeros:

```
>>> '\U0001D15D'
''
>>> '\U0001D15D'.encode('unicode_escape')
b'\\U0001d15d'
```

(And yes, the U+1D15D codepoint (MUSICAL SYMBOL WHOLE NOTE) is in the above example, but your browser font may not be able to render it, showing a place-holder glyph (a box or question mark) instead.

Because you used a `\uabcd` escape, you replaced `a` in `abc` with two characters, the codepoint U+1D15 (`ᴕ`, latin letter small capital ou), and the ASCII character `D`. Using a 32-bit unicode literal works:

```
>>> import re
>>> print(re.sub('a', '\U0001D15D', 'abc' ))
bc
>>> print(re.sub('a', u'\U0001D15D', 'abc' ).encode('unicode_escape'))
b'\\U0001d15dbc'
```

where again the U+1D15D codepoint could be displayed by your font as a placeholder glyph instead.

Answer (score 1):

By the way, you do not need the `re` module for this. You could use [str.translate](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate):

```
>>> 'abc'.translate({ord('a'):'\U0001D15D'})
'bc'
```

Comment: It was probably just an illustration, a short example to demonstrate the perceived problem.